# QLabel is not clickable in my program

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt

The program is working correctly but QLabel is not clickable.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import bs4
import urllib.request
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

webpage=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.boluolay.com/')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')

class ButonluPencere(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(640, 480)

        buton = QPushButton(self)
        buton.setText("Bolu Olay Gazetesi")
        buton.setGeometry(400,10,100,50)

        buton.clicked.connect(self.getir)
        kayan=QScrollBar(self)
        kayan.setGeometry(370, 60, 16, 160)

        buton.clicked.connect(self.boluolay_koseyazilari)
        buton.clicked.connect(self.boluolay_manset)

    def getir(self):
        boluolay_manset=QLabel(self)
        boluolay_manset.setText("MANŞET")
        boluolay_manset.setGeometry(100,-15,500,70)
        boluolay_manset.show()
        satirBoyu=20
        i=1
        for yazarlar in soup.find_all("a",class_="main_cuff"):
                for yazar_adi in yazarlar.find_all("div",class_="title"):
                    etiket = QLabel(self)
                    etiket.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
                    etiket.setGeometry(100,satirBoyu,500,satirBoyu+20)
                    etiket.setText('<a href="http://www.boluolay.com'+yazarlar['href']+'">'+str(i) + ". " + yazar_adi.text.strip() + '</a>')
                    etiket.show()
                    i+=1
                    satirBoyu += 10

    def boluolay_manset(self):
        boluolay_manset=QLabel(self)
        boluolay_manset.setText("DİĞER HABERLER")
        boluolay_manset.setGeometry(100,180,500,70)
        boluolay_manset.show()
        satirBoyu=140
        i=1
        for manset in soup.find_all("ul",class_="news marginTen"):
                for diger_haber in manset("a",class_="title"):
                    etiket = QLabel(self)
                    etiket.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
                    etiket.setGeometry(100,satirBoyu,500,satirBoyu+50)
                    etiket.setText('<a href="http://www.boluolay.com/'+manset.find('a')['href']+'">'+str(i) + ". " + diger_haber.text.strip() + '</a>')
                    etiket.show()
                    i+=1
                    satirBoyu += 10

    def boluolay_koseyazilari(self):
        boluolay_ky=QLabel(self)
        boluolay_ky.setText("KÖŞE YAZARLARI")
        boluolay_ky.setGeometry(100,450,500,70)
        boluolay_ky.show()
        webpage=urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.boluolay.com/yazarlar.html')
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
        satirBoyu=320
        i=1
        for manset in soup.find_all("div",id="yazark"):
                for mansetb in manset.find_all("b"):
                    for yazar_konu in manset("span"):
                        ab=yazar_konu
                    etiket = QLabel(self)
                    etiket.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
                    etiket.setGeometry(100,satirBoyu,500,satirBoyu+50)
                    etiket.setText('<a href="http://www.boluolay.com/'+manset.find('a')['href']+'">'+str(i) + ". " + ab.text.strip() + '</a>')
                    etiket.show()
                    i+=1
                    satirBoyu += 10

uygulama = QApplication(sys.argv)
pencere = ButonluPencere()
pencere.show()
uygulama.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on URLs of your QLabel, then you would need to set a few more properties for it (aside from `setOpenExternalLinks`) like `setTextInteractionFlags` to `Qt::TextBrowserInteraction` and `setTextFormat` to `Qt::RichText`

Edit (add these lined to every label that you need to click URL on `etiket` as example):

```
etiket.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
etiket.setTextInteractionFlags(Qt.TextBrowserInteraction)
etiket.setTextFormat(Qt.RichText)
```

Comment: @BithynianPrince i've edited post, can you at least past it on you own?

Answer (score 0):

QLabel is not clickable generally, but you can overload `QLabel.mousePressEvent` or `QLabel.mouseReleaseEvent` method to recognize clicked signal; like this:

```
class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.t=QLabel('Click Me',self)
        self.t.mousePressEvent=self.labelClick

    def labelClick(self,e):
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print('Clicked')
        QLabel.mousePressEvent(self.t,e)
```